# Remove image from treectrl items

Tags: image, wxpython, treecontrol

I add images to wxpython treectrl items with `tree.SetItemImage`. Later the image shall be removed. How can I do it? I found only the `SetItemImage` method, I have not found anything like `RemoveItemImage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very obvious, but you can remove the item's image by calling `SetItemImage` and passing `-1` through for the image parameter

```
tree.SetItemImage(node, -1)
```